# How to modify every data frame in a list in R

Tags: r, dataframe

i really didn't found the solution even it's seems easy, any way

i have a list a data frames, and i have a very large code (it's not just an apply or else, a bunch of for loop and creating tables ...) that i want to apply to each dataframe, to each element of the list,

i thought of making a loop on this list, and browsing it data frame by data frame, but how can extract the current element to work on it ?

(my code is about 450 lines, i just wanna instead of replacing the data frame name with the next name, it just will be automatic)

```
dbR<-list()
for (i in datedeb:datefin)
{
   sqlst<-paste("SELECT * FROM `cl4d6-2015/09/",sprintf("%02d",i),"`",sep="")
   nomcl<-paste0("cl",sprintf("%02d",i),sep="")
   dbR[[nomcl]]<-dbGetQuery(db,sqlst)
}


for (i in dbR)
{
   #mycode
}
```

Comment: I don't see where your code puts the data.frames into a list. Instead they are assigned into the global environment, which is a mistake. Regarding your main question: `lapply` was designed for this.

Comment: i think you not needed `assign(` simply add you `df` into `list` for example `dbR[[i]]=dt` then if need you can add names to list elements `names(dbR)=......`

Comment: sorry guys a mistake, i correct it, so my list dbR does have the date frames

Comment: If `L` is a list of data frames then this produces a new list with a new column appended to each one:  `lapply(L, function(DF) { DF$new <- 1; DF})`

Comment: but my code is about 450 lines, i just wanna instead of replacing the data frame name with the next data frame, it just will be automatic

Comment: @Mamoud I would also consider to break the codes into modules if you need 450 lines to complete the task...

Comment: @Mamoud Study G. Grothendieck's comment carefully. You only need to wrap your code into a function.

Comment: @Hao, ok i'll see about that, thanks

Comment: @Roland,@G. Grothendieck, yeah i thought about it but i thought therre is another way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the below example code.

```
dbR <- sapply(1:30, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE, FUN = function(i) {
  dt <- dbGetQuery(db, paste("SELECT * FROM `cl4d6-2015/09/",
                             sprintf("%02d", i), "`", sep = ""))
  #mycode
  return(dt)
})
```

The code above will operate across `1:30` similar to a `for` loop, except the output is automatically saved as individual list entries. We save the list of dataframes out to `dbR`. You can also add your code operating on the dataframes subsequent to the data read-in.

`sapply()` with `USE.NAMES = TRUE` and `simplify = FALSE` will operate like `lapply`, but retaining the list names/values.

The `apply` family of functions is not always intuitive, but they're powerful and fast! They're also easily translated into parallel operations. I recommend getting comfortable with them.

Comment: can I with function (){mycode for each data frame}, use objects from the previous data frame ?? that's why i wanted a for loop so i can return and grab variables of the previous or of the next data frame

Comment: @Mamoud, can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: well for exemple, for the data frame of the day 17-09-2015, i have to know the numbers of persones who where present at home until midnight for the day 16-09-2015.

Comment: and if for exemple, the data frame i'm workin on it's a weekend, so i have to skip it to next data drame, or make anothers changes on it

Comment: that's why i asked from the beging of just how can i extract data frame by data frame to work on it easely